# AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'parseArrivalDate'

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to save field from API in his match field in my database, but I'm getting an error: **AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'parseArrivalDate'**

First I convert the type of it from string to datetime, I printed to see the type and the output is: **<class 'datetime.datetime'>**

But when I tried to save the value of **parseArrivalDate** also same for departureDate (I'm trying to save first one of them and will make the other) into the database I got the error. Can someone say why it's happened?

I also tried different way to convert it everything what I found and researched like make_aware and etc but without success with the saving.

```
from datetime import datetime

arrivalDate = response.json()['bookings'][0]['arrival']['date']
        print(arrivalDate)
        parseArrivalDate = datetime.strptime(arrivalDate, '%Y-%m-%d')
        print(type(parseArrivalDate))
    
        departureDate = response.json()['bookings'][0]['departure']['date']
    
        patientIdWebFlow = response.json()['patient']['patient_id']
    
        patientsIdDB = Patient.objects.values('coreapi_id')

#here I loop through the id's and check if the record from API match  with some of the records in my database and tried to save the date for this id.
        for patientIdDB in patientsIdDB:
            if patientIdWebFlow == int(patientIdDB['coreapi_id']):
                print('they matched')
                datesPatients, created = Patient.objects.get_or_create(
                        coreapi_id=int(patientIdDB['coreapi_id']),
                        defaults=dict(
                            date_arrival=patientIdDB.parseArrivalDate,
                            date_departure=patientIdDB.departureDate,
                        ),
                    )
            else:
                print('they not matched')
```

**my models.py:**

```
class Patient(models.Model):
    coreapi_id = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    date_arrival = models.DateField(null=True)
    date_departure = models.DateField(null=True)
```

Comment: This code makes very little sense. You're looping over all patients in the database, why? If you only mean to update one, do so with e.g. `Patient.objects.filter(coreapi_id=patientIdDB['coreapi_id']).update(...)`

Comment: I though I need to loop them so I can make the condition after that?

Comment: The loop is still needed as `.values()` returns a dictionary for each patient in the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
defaults=dict(
    date_arrival=patientIdDB.parseArrivalDate,
    date_departure=patientIdDB.departureDate,
),
```

You are accessing `parseArrivalDate` atrribute of `patientIdDB (an instance of Parent)` which is not a field of `Patient` class. That's why you are getting this error.

From the code, you may want to set `parseArrivalDate` and `departureDate` variable like following.

```py
defaults=dict(
    date_arrival=parseArrivalDate,
    date_departure=departureDate,
),
```

Here is the full code after fix,

```py
from datetime import datetime

arrivalDate = response.json()['bookings'][0]['arrival']['date']
print(arrivalDate)
parseArrivalDate = datetime.strptime(arrivalDate, '%Y-%m-%d')
print(type(parseArrivalDate))

departureDate = response.json()['bookings'][0]['departure']['date']

patientIdWebFlow = response.json()['patient']['patient_id']

patientsIdDB = Patient.objects.values('coreapi_id')

# here I loop through the id's and check if the record from API match  with some of the records in my database and tried to save the date for this id.
for patientIdDB in patientsIdDB:
    if patientIdWebFlow == int(patientIdDB['coreapi_id']):
        print('they matched')
        datesPatients, created = Patient.objects.get_or_create(
            coreapi_id=int(patientIdDB['coreapi_id']),
            defaults=dict(
                date_arrival=parseArrivalDate,
                date_departure=departureDate,
            ),
        )
    else:
        print('they not matched')
```

Comment: hi and thank you for your reply @Md. Nahidur Rahman. arrival_date and departure_date are fields in my database and I'm trying to save in them the date from an API which field I set to arrivalDate and departureDate. I tried your solution but I still get AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'date_arrival'.

Comment: I have updated my answer with the thing you mention, try now.

Comment: Thank you, I just tried and now the error is gone but I it still don't save in the fields. Do you know why is this happened? Maybe I write wrong the get_or_create function?

Comment: Use `update_or_create` instead of `get_or_create`. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#update-or-create

Comment: No, `patientIdDB` is not a model instance since OP is using `.values()`. It will be a dict with only a `coreapi_id` key.

Comment: Thank you))))  @Md.NahidurRahman update_or_create made it to save the fields.

Answer (score 0):

A more correct implementation that doesnt' loop through every Patient in the database just to find exactly one is

```
from datetime import datetime

json = response.json()
booking = json['bookings'][0]

arrivalDate = booking['arrival']['date']
departureDate = booking['departure']['date']
patientIdWebFlow = json['patient']['patient_id']
parseArrivalDate = datetime.strptime(arrivalDate, '%Y-%m-%d')

did_update = Patient.objects.filter(coreapi_id=patientIdWebFlow).update(
    date_arrival=parseArrivalDate,
    date_departure=departureDate,
)
if not did_update:
    raise ValueError("No records got updated.")
```